# Gson property order in android

Tags: java, android, gson

I have integrated Gson to create the json used in a request for an android application.

Here is my model class

```
public class TwitterUser {

@Expose
public String gid;
public String icon_url;
public Boolean is_app_user;
@Expose
public String displayName;

public TwitterUser(String l, String i, String url, Boolean app_user) {
    gid = i;
    displayName = l;
    icon_url = url;
    is_app_user = app_user;
}

public TwitterUser(String l, String i) {
    gid = i;
    displayName = l;
}

public String getGid() {
    return gid;
}

public void setGid(String gid) {
    this.gid = gid;
}

public String getIcon_url() {
    return icon_url;
}

public void setIcon_url(String icon_url) {
    this.icon_url = icon_url;
}

public Boolean getIs_app_user() {
    return is_app_user;
}

public void setIs_app_user(Boolean is_app_user) {
    this.is_app_user = is_app_user;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}

public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
}
```

Here is how i create the json request

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();              
gson.toJson(twitterUser));
```

But when I send the request to the server - the order will be rejected. I have to change the request's field order to stay:

1. `gid`
2. `displayName`

but gson creates other way around, is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Added an Answer which should cover you problem - do you need additional help?

Comment: Hey Mr.G, I see that there is no response here :) But still do you need some more help for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Gson **doesn't** support definition of property order *out of the box*, but there are other libraries that do. **Jackson** allows defining this with [`@JsonPropertyOrder`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html), for example.

But of course Gson has it's way so you can do it by creating your very own Json serializer:

```
public class TwitterUserSerializer implements JsonSerializer<TwitterUser> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(TwitterUser twitterUser, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        object.add("gid", context.serialize(twitterUser.getGid());
        object.add("displayName", context.serialize(twitterUser.getDisplayName());
        // ...
        return object;
    }
}
```

Then of course you need to pass this serializer to Gson during Setup like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(TwitterUser.class, new TwitterUserSerializer()).excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
String json = gson.toJson(twitterUser);
```

#### See also:

- [Gson User Guide - Custom serializers and deserializers](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ)