# Gson different results in Java vs. Android

Tags: java, android, gson

I get different results when I run the following code in Java (Eclipse) and in Android:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class TestJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Test test = new Test();

        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(test));
    }

    public static class Test {

        public String b = "b";
        public String c = "c";
        public String a = "a";
    }
}
```

Result Java (JDK 8):

{
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c",
  "a": "a"
}

Result Android 10:

{
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c"
}

Both with the same version of Gson 2.8.6.

Why this? Please help.

Comment: you mean the order of json properties ?

Comment: The results are the same. It's only the order that is different. Order is likely not guaranteed, and it shouldn't be because it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, I mean the sort order. And I know, the result is technical the same. But I want to understand why the order is different. Both systems uses the same JDK and the same reflection. 

In my case, I want to display informations as json in the order of fields declaration, because the json is better to read for customer service.

Comment: You are missing a layer in your development. If you want a specific order you should read the json representation (the string), pick the properties, and sort them as you want before presenting the info to the user. The order of the properties is meaningless in a java class as well as in a javascript object.

Comment: there is [an adapter to help in keeping the property order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29732830/4648586), and gson is [known to not deal](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/131#issuecomment-83701402) with the property order at all. as for why the property order is different on java and android, maybe the underneath reflection api is to blame.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa, your comment is the only sensible answer. I could tell them how to maintain property order dynamically, but the question isn't how but why.

Comment: Order isn't maintained in GSON.  It basically uses a Hashmap, and the order of items in a hashmap depends on a dozen different things, including exact hash algorithm used on the keys, the default size of the hash, the insertion order, etc.  I'd be more surprised if they were the same than that they're different.  And in JSON the order doesn't matter (even in JS, there's no promise that fields remain in the order they came in from a JSON string), so anything that depends on the order being maintained is broken.